# How to prevent links displayed on :focus/:active from auto-clicking on a touch screen?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, focus, mobile-website

I am designing a sidebar, which hides menu entries unless the user hovers over it/ or taps it on a mobile device. The problem occurs on mobile devices (or when I test my code in chrome with mobile mode toggled in developer options). In touch mode, if I tap on the sidebar where a menu entry would be displayed after focus, the newly visible menu entry is automatically clicked. Is there a way to disable auto-clicking of links that newly become visible under the pointer?

My preferred solution would be pure CSS - but I can work with vanilla JS if there is not other option.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n7nsdL49/

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">This</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">is</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">a</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">menu.</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color : green;
}
.menu {
  display: none
}
.sidebar:hover, .sidebar:focus {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}
.sidebar:hover .menu, .sidebar:focus .menu {
  display: block;
}
```

**EDIT:** I have tried playing around with `pointer-events` option but it seems to have no effect on links being auto-clicked when displayed.

Comment: Either don't use `:hover` and `:focus` on non-clickable items (like `<div>`, `<li>`, etc) or use something like modernizr and use `.no-touch .sidebar :hover`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around auto-clicking of newly visible links by using the `animation` property. Essentially, I animate the `menu` class to become visible a small interval after getting `focus` or `hover`. That way the clicks do not register if a newly displayed link is below a pointer event. Here is the [fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nu9vr1sm/](https://jsfiddle.net/nu9vr1sm/).

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">This</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">is</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">a</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">menu.</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color : green;
}
.menu {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;    /* <= include this property */
}
.sidebar:hover, .sidebar:focus {
  width: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}

/* ================== */
/* THE IMPORTANT PART */
/* ================== */
.sidebar:hover .menu,
.sidebar:focus .menu {
        display: block;                /* make it part of the DOM */
        animation: fadeIn 0.05s;       /* make it visible after a while */
        animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* make it retain final visibility */
    }

@keyframes fadeIn {
  99% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
/* ================== */
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to avoid playing with the display and instead hide it on the left side by using:

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color : green;
  left:-20%;
}

.sidebar:hover, .sidebar:focus {
  background-color: red;
  left:0;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n7nsdL49/2/

You could even add a transition

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  background-color : green;
  left:-20%;
  transition: left 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: This suffers from the same problem on mobile. The moment I tap on the sidebar on the position where the menu list will later appear, the menu appears, and the link underneath my pointer is clicked.